# Spring Neo4j Template throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-social

I am working with spring social to get a users friends and add them to a database but every time i compile and the app launches it throws this error My class is below the error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/see-my-style] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getMappingPolicy(Neo4jTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getMappingPolicy(Neo4jTemplate.java:656)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.social.quickstart.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is the class im working with

```
package org.springframework.social.quickstart;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jOperations;

import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.FacebookProfile;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.PagedList;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Reference;
import org.springframework.social.quickstart.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Simple little @Controller that invokes Facebook and renders the result.
 * The injected {@link Facebook} reference is configured with the required authorization credentials for the current user behind the scenes.
 * @author Keith Donald
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private final Facebook facebook;
        private static final String DB_PATH = "target/neo4j-hello-db";
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);

        Neo4jOperations neo = new Neo4jTemplate(graphDb);


    @Inject
    public HomeController(Facebook facebook) {
        this.facebook = facebook;    
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
        List<Reference> friends = facebook.friendOperations().getFriends();

                for(Reference friend: friends)
                {
                    neo.save(friend.getName());
                }
        return "home";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the Friend is annotated with `@NodeEntity`.
2. Tell spring the location (package(s)) of all your node entities so that it knows the mapping.
3. Instead of creating the graph db yourself, let spring manage it for you (use neo4j namespace)
4. I think you should save the `Friend` entity instead of name. i.e. change the below

   neo.save(friend.getName());

to

```
neo.save(friend);
```